# Is there an application that works as DBCC wizard?

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

DBCC (DB Consistency Check) commands are powerful tools but they don,t have a graphical user interface. now Is there a application that works like DBCC wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the advanced options for DBCC (such as trying to repair corruption whilst allowing dataloss) are probably best left for experienced DBAs - so perhaps that is the reason why there is no GUI.

You can, of course, do a standard checkDB via a maintenance plan, which has a wizard. Easy enough, and a best practice to run a checkDB at least once a week.

Slightly off topic, but I did see a Microsoft Connect ticket to include the "last known good date" in the system view sys.databases in a future version of SQL Server.